# Правильное использование clientX

Tags: javascript, css

Надо отодвинуть элемент с указанным ID от левого края экрана. Как это делается? Предположение такое, но оно не работает:

```
document.getElementById('Pop_aus').style.left = document.body.clientX+'px';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто

```
document.getElementById('Pop_aus').style.margin-left='20px';
```

Это отодвинет на 20 пикселей либо `padding-left:20px`;

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно отодвинуть не на фиксированное количество пикселей, а на количество пикселей завязанных на положение мыши... Потому я пытаюсь использовать clientX, но в упор не могу найти, как это правильно сделать... тут вопрос скорее синтаксиса.

Comment: тогда ваш код плюс position:absolute; для данного блока.

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: для начала сделайте 
<pre>alert(document.body.clientX+'px');
</pre>
чтобы убедиться что правильно считается

Comment: e=document.body.clientX+20+'px';
alert (e);

результат на экране: NaNpx

Comment: У вас код только для ИЕ. Советую разобрать вот этот код для себя: [координаты мыши относительно документа](http://www.fpublisher.ru/cms_fpublisher/javascript_develop/new703).

Comment: нет clienX в отличие от pageX решение кроссбраузерное... решение оказалось вот таким: e = event.clientX + 20 + 'px'; alert (e);

но все равно спасибо )